# How to only get datetime without hours minutes and seconds python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, forecast

I am doing a forecast with FBProhpet and suddenly when I do the forecast, only the forecasted dates (ds) ate being displayed with hours minutes and seconds
See pictures for more information.

Any ideas on how to fix that [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
df['ds']=pd.to_datetime(df['ds'])
df['ds']=df['ds'].dt.date
```